# What does "a Munich-like capitulation by President Obama" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Europe’s disarray will tempt Putin to subjugate the Baltic nations of Estonia, Latvia and Lithuania under the pretense of protecting Russian minorities there, who, by the way, have no desire to be Moscow’s subjects again. These states are part of NATO, and the U.S. and other NATO members are under treaty obligation to defend them from a Russian assault. **A Munich-like capitulation by President Obama** would destroy NATO, the alliance that enabled the West to win the Cold War. The Balts are visibly fearful that their days of independence are numbered. Poland is also increasingly anxious about its security.

The paragraph above is an excerpt from the magazine *Forbes USA* (20160726). What confuses me is the phrase "A Munich-like capitulation by President Obama". Could someone please explain it to me? Thank you!

According to the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, capitulate means: 1.to accept or agree to something that you have been opposing for a long time; 2. to accept defeat by your enemies in a war.

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: History SE.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry for that. Next time, I will post questions about history on the website History SE. Thanks for reminding me. :)

Comment: The question is how to discern that it is a history question if you don't recognize the connection to the treaty? By the way is every question regarding a word that has a historic connotation a history question? Etymology is explicitly part of this SE.

Comment: I think one could argue "Munich Pact/Agreement" is a standard English phrase nowadays. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/munich-pact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the writer is referring to the 1938 Munich Agreement, in which France, the UK and Italy signed a treaty with Germany basically saying "OK, you can keep the places you've annexed (eg portions of Czechoslovakia) so far, as long as you don't do anything else bad".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich_Agreement

It's historically seen as a colossal mistake, allowing Hitler to gain even more land and power before eventually being forced into World War 2 after he completely disregarded the treaty (which was really just a delaying tactic) and invaded Poland.

So, the piece is comparing Obama to, for example, British Prime Minister of the time Neville Chamberlain, one of the signatories, and is implying that if Obama doesn't act more forcefully to stop Russian expansion now then we will pay for it later, eg with the collapse of NATO.

Note that I'm just interpreting the piece and offer none of my own opinion about Obama's actions.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think your answer is correct. It is quite reasonable. Without your explanations on the historic event on the 1938 Munich Agreement, never would I understand what the author wants to say here.